# .Net8 primary constructors and fields with default values [S3604: Remove the member initializer, all constructors set an initial value for the member]

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0

I want to migrate from .Net6 to .Net8 and use primary constructors. It works super nice with normal dependency injection, but I don't know what to do if I have a field, which just uses a default value. For example in here:

#### Example #1

```cs
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private readonly IDependecyService dependencyService;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, TypedId?> typedIdDictionary;

    public MyClass(IDependecyService dependencyService)
    {
        this.dependencyService = dependencyService;

        typedIdDictionary = new();
    }

   ...
}
```

I transformed it into:

```cs
public class MyClass(IDependecyService dependencyService) : IMyClass
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, TypedId?> typedIdDictionary; = new();

...
}
```

But then I get a warning

> error S3604: Remove the member initializer, all constructors set an initial value for the member. (https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-3604)

#### Another example

From:

```cs
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private readonly string valueFromConfig;

    public MyClass(IConfig config)
    {
        this.valueFromConfig = config.Value;
    }

   ...
}
```

Into:

```cs
public class MyClass(IConfig config) : IMyClass
{
    private readonly string valueFromConfig; = config.Value;

...
}
```

But then I get the same warning.

#### Question

How to deal with properly according to .Net rules and code style?

I tried putting default values `= new()` into primary constructor but it takes only value types or `null`.

Comment: That's not a C# error. The SonarQube version you use doesn't understand primary constructors. [This dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ru4GM6) shows there's no problem with your code, beyond a few typos

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a C# error. It seems the SonarQube version used doesn't fully support C# 12. Official C# 12 support was added in [9.13](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-dotnet/releases/tag/9.13.0.79967). The release notes include fixes for 6 false negatives involving primary constructors :

```
8143 - [C#] Fix S107 FN: support primary constructors
8131 - [C#] Fix S1117 FN: support primary constructors
8122 - [C#] Fix S1118 FN: empty primary constructor
8096 - [C#] Fix S3254 FN: primary constructors
8092 - [C#] Fix S3253 FN: primary parameterless constructors
8071 - [C#] Fix S2234 FN: primary constructors for records, classes and structs
```